# c# marshaling floating pointer

Tags: c#, .net, interop

I have to call a c++ function from c# app. The function is defined as Bool `GetTemperaure(float *value)`. I have defined as below.

```
[DllImport("xxx.dll")]
public static extern bool GetTemperaure(out System.Single value);
```

When i call GetTemperaure, sometimes i am not getting the proper value. I have just put an expection block around this call. Divided by zero exception appears some time.

What ever i have defined is that correct? any ideas why the exception is coming?

Thanks
Raju

Comment: The signature looks correct. Are you sure the C function is not causing a DivideByZero or perhaps it expects an input value?

Answer (score 0):

The question says "Bool" did you mean bool or BOOL?  They have different meanings in C++.   Thus you might have the incorrect prototype.   You might need UnmanagedType.Bool or System.Boolean depending on the C++ side.